# How to insert multiple values into database using mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using a form where user adding one or monre than one input values

```
<form class="col s12" action="my_resume.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col s12"  style="padding-top: 12px;">
        <div class="col s12 m12 ">
        <div id="dynamic_field"> 
        <div> 
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Title</label>
                <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]"></textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Location</label>

                <textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea>
            </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label>
                <input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  />
             </div>
             <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label>
                <input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value=""  />
             </div>
              <div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label>
                <input id="year" name="year[]" type="text" value=""  />
             </div>
             <div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add More</button></div>  
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="input-field col s6">
           <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" 
     type="submit" name="submit">Save
             <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
           </button>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

</div>
</form>
```

user can add more information about his education by clicking on add more button and when click on close button then div will b disappeared

```
<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){  
  var i=1;  
  $('#add').click(function(){ 
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Title</label><textarea  class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;" id="title" name="title[]"></textarea></div><div class="col s12 m12 "><label for="title">Location</label><textarea  id="location" name="location[]" class="materialize-textarea" style="padding: 0px;"></textarea></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Marks</label><input id="marks" name="marks[]" type="text" value=""  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Division</label><input id="divsion" name="divsion[]" type="text" value=""  /></div><div class="col s3 m3 "><label for="title">Year</label><input id="year" name="year[]" type="text" value=""  /></div><div class="col s3 m3"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger button btn_remove">X</button></div></div>');  


$('.btn_remove').click(function(){ 
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
});
 </script>
```

I am confuse that how to insert multiple input values into database I am tried like this way.

```
<?php
  // Submit Form
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


         $field1_array = isset($_POST['marks']) ? $_POST['divsion'] : array();
           $total_rows = count($field1_array);

        for($i=0 ; $i<$total_rows;$i++){
            $trans = array("degree"=>$_POST['title'][$i],"location"=>$_POST['location'][$i],"marks"=>$_POST['marks'][$i],"divsion"=>$_POST['divsion'][$i],"passing_year"=>$_POST['year'][$i]);
        $query = ("Insert into tbl_student_education".$trans);
        }
        }           
 ?>
  <script>alert('Record Save Successfully');</script>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: why would you name a text area like this `name="location[]"`

Comment: because there is multiple textarea show when user click on add more button

Comment: You are only declaring variables there, you are not performing any actual database query.

Comment: And trying to “append” any array to a string is not going to achieve what you think it does, this will result in the _word_ “Array” being appended in this place.

Comment: so my question is that how to insert multple inpur values into database?.. I am confuding in php query

Comment: Your query is wrong .. where is actual query is executed ..?

Comment: @RahulPawar.. this is no actual query executed.. I only want to know that how to insert multple inpur values into database

Comment: @Hayamkhan you are doing right.. I just want to see you $_POST array. how is looking ..

Comment: he is looking only this `Insert into tbl_student_educationArray` when echo mysql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code for inserting multiple data

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Submit Form
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $total_rows = !empty($_POST['marks'])?count($_POST['marks']):0;
    if ($total_rows > 0) {
        for($i=0 ; $i<$total_rows;$i++){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_student_education (degree, location, marks,divsion,passing_year) VALUES ('".$_POST['title'][$i]."', '".$_POST['location'][$i]."', '".$_POST['marks'][$i]."','".$_POST['divsion'][$i]."','".$_POST['year'][$i]."')";
            $query = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
        }
        if ($query) {
            ?><script>alert('Record Save Successfully');</script><?php
        }else{
            ?><script>alert('somethings went wrong');</script><?php
        }
    }else{
        ?><script>alert('No data');</script><?php
    }

}           
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for supporting me